# Not able to login to Tuleap after full installation due to TCP IP port configuration

Tags: ip, tcp, ports, tuleap

Not able to login to Tuleap after full installation, as all the ports are in listen mode and 9091 port is not visible in ports.How to over come this and solve.

With IP address we are getting tuleap login page, after entering credentials it is not displaying any thing

Regards
Suneel

Answer (score 0):

If you get to the login page then it means you have done something right. You should check that you can also access the login page in https.

A blank page should result in a message in

```
/var/log/httpd/error.log
```

It would help if you could include any such errors in the question above.